# FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Android

Tags: android, file, ioerror

I try this file writer/reader code segment for test:

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "LM/lm_lisdat_01.txt");
FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
outputStream.write(("test").getBytes());
outputStream.close();

File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), "LM/lm_lisdat_01.txt");
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file)));
```

In the 4. row i got this error message below but the "lm_lisdat_01.txt" file was created in LM directory:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/hu.abisoft.lm/files/LM/lm_lisdat_01.txt: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Can help anyone for answer this (i think simple) question? I'm newby in Android. Thank you!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are creating the file in one directory and trying to open it for input in another.

`Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` is /storage/emulated/0

`getExternalFilesDir(null)` is /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/hu.abisoft.lm/files

Use the same directory for file creation and input.

Answer (score 0):

Please see changes. Your path was wrong.

And also check whether file exists or not.

```
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "LM/lm_lisdat_01.txt");
    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
    outputStream.write(("test").getBytes());
    outputStream.close();

    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "LM/lm_lisdat_01.txt");//changes here
if(file.exists())
   { 

  BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file)));
   }
```